# How to get all Products within a Category or sub-category

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nopcommerce

I'm trying to get all the products within one Category, I want to search by CategoryId. So I want to get a list filled with all products where categoryId is for example 3.

How can I do this, I'm using NopCommerce 3.10.

Someone on the Nop forum achieved it using the following line:

```
_productService.SearchProductVariants(categoryId, 0, string.Empty, false, 0, int.MaxValue, false);
```

But since I use 3.10 and ProductVariants are replaced by Products, I can't use this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the result returned back give you an IEnumerable<T> back? You could perhaps use LINQ after getting back the results?

Comment: I'm, using NopCommerce and there must be a method I can use for returning those values but I can't figure out in which class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

**For all products within 1 categoryid:**

```
        NopEngine _engine;
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns IPagedList(Product) filled with all products from selected CategoryId
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Categoryid"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IPagedList<Product> GetAllProductsFromCategory(int Categoryid)
        {
            _engine = new NopEngine();
            var _productService = _engine.Resolve<IProductService>();
            List<int> CategoryIds = new List<int>();
            CategoryIds.Add(Categoryid);
            return _productService.SearchProducts(categoryIds: CategoryIds);
        }
```

**For all products:**

```
        NopEngine _engine;
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns IPagedList(Product) filled with all products, without selection
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IPagedList<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            _engine = new NopEngine();
            var _allService = _engine.Resolve<IProductService>();
            return _allService.SearchProducts();
        }
```

Comment: I get an object reference not set to an instance of an object ecxeption when i call _engine.Resolve<IProductService>();

Comment: Did you add: `NopEngine _engine = new NopEngine();` before you execute that sentence?